# DRY when passing similar functions to Scala map()

Tags: scala, dry

```
def doubleList(noList:List[Int]) = {
    val result = noList.map{ number =>
        number*2
    }
    result
}

def halfList(noList:List[Int]) = {
    val result = noList.map{ number =>
        number/2
    }
    result
}

def mapFunctionDRY(noList:List[Int])(codeBlock: () => Int) = {

}

println(halfList(List(1,2,3)))
println(doubleList(List(1,2,4)))
```

I was playing around with scala and noticed violation of DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) in the above two functions `doubleList` and `halfList`. I want the code common in both the function to be isolated and just pass the code block which is different. That way my code would not be violating DRY principle. I know that you could pass in code block as argument in scala. That is what I intend to do in `mapFunctionDRY`

I want mapFunctionDRY to be in this way

```
def mapFunctionDRY(noList:List[Int])(codeBlock: () => Int) = {
    noList.map{ number =>
        codeBlock()
    }
}
```

And code in `doubleList` and `halfList` to be similar to this

```
def doubleList(noList:List[Int]) = { mapFunctionDRY(noList){ () => number*2 } }
```

But I would get a compilation error if I do such thing. How can I make the code pass in as the parameter in this case to avoid violation of DRY. Can this code be reduced further to keep it DRY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent job that map does quite DRY:

```
def double(x: Int) = x * 2
def half(x: Int) = x / 2
val xs = List(1,2,3,4)
xs.map(double)
// List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)

xs.map(half)
// List[Int] = List(0, 1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: i.e. List(1,2,3,4) map(_*2)  and List(1,2,3,4) map(_/2)

Answer (score 2):

The compilation error occurs because you want to map each Int to another Int. `codeBlock: () => Int` is a function that takes no argument.

`codeBlock: Int => Int` should do what you want. Then you can define something like this:

```
def doubleList(noList:List[Int]) = { mapFunctionDRY(noList){ (number : Int) => number*2 } }
```

Haven't tested it though.

Edit: And like the others said. This function is not really useful because it's like map but weaker in the sense that it can only be applied to List[Int]

Answer (score 2):

Why are you building a wrapper around `map`, which actually provides the dry-est solution to your problem? I would suggest a different strategy:

```
val mapDouble = (x: Int) => x * 2
val mapHalf = (x: Int) => x / 2
List(1, 2, 3).map(mapDouble)
List(1, 2, 3).map(mapHalf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions operate on one element of a list. Therefore instead of `codeBlock` being a `() => Int`, I would change it to `(Int) => Int`. So given one element of a list what do you want to do with it.

This results in the following code:

```
def mapFunctionDRY(noList:List[Int])(elementFn: (Int) => Int) = {
  noList.map{ number =>
    elementFn(number)
  }
}
```

And if you're into short code, then the equivalent code is:

```
def mapFunctionDRY(noList:List[Int])(elementFn: (Int) => Int) = noList.map(elementFn)
```

There are many other ways to keep being DRY. For an example your could define the operations separately to be able to reuse them:

```
val doubleOperation: Int => Int = _ * 2
val halfOperation: Int => Int = _ / 2
def doubleList(noList:List[Int]) = noList.map(doubleOperation)
def halfList(noList:List[Int]) = noList.map(halfOperation)
```

Or you could use function currying to save yourself one line of code:

```
def mapFunction(fn: (Int) => Int)(noList: List[Int]) = noList.map(fn)
val doubleList = mapFunction(_ * 2)
val halfList = mapFunction(_ / 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Currying in this regard.

```
 def func(factor:Double)(noList:List[Int]) ={
     val result = noList.map{ number =>
            number*factor
        }
        result
```

Now you can pass this function with func(0.5f)(noList) or func(1.0f)(noList)

You could even have References to the different Versions of your Function.

```
halfed = x:List[Int] => func(0.5f)(x)
doubled = x:List[Int] => func(2.0f)(x)
```